# Python import problems when importing my own package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

My PyCharm project was structured in this way:

```
 MyPrj
 |_ src
    |_ main.py       

 MyPackage
 |_ src
 |  |_ MyPackage
 |     |_ __init__.py
 |     |_ MyModule.py
 |_ setup.py
```

In `main.py` I added this line: `from MyPackage import MyModule`.
I succesfully installed this module using anaconda3 (`~/anaconda3/bin/pip install .`). After having experienced some problem regarding the fact that `MyPackage` was not found, I re-installed anaconda3 and the code was finally working.

Now I have added another module `MySub.py` in `MyPackage/src/MyPackage` and then I have imported it in `MyModule.py` (`from MySub import sub`, where `sub` is a class correctly defined in `MySub.py`). After having upgraded my package in anaconda3, when I try to run `main.py` I get the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'sub1'`, however if I look into the `site-packages` folder of anaconda3 `MySub.py` is present. How to solve this problem?

This is my `setup.py` file:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup


def read(fname):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()


setup(
    name='MyPackage',
    version='0.1',
    description='my description',
    long_description=read('README.txt'),
    packages=['MyPackage'],
    package_dir={'MyPackage': 'src/MyPackage'},
    zip_safe=False
)
```

my `__init__.py` file is empty.

Comment: Did you actually put `.py` on your `import` statements?

Comment: Sorry it was a typo I corrected it

Comment: We need to see a real [mcve], not a few lines of misremembered imports and directory trees.

Comment: @user2357112 I've put more info and added the `setup.py` file. If other information is needed tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
from MyPackage import module.py
```

to:

```
from MyPackage import module
```

`module` is the name of the Python module; `module.py` is the name of the file itself, and is not allowed in an import statement. In fact, when you do `import module.py`, the Python import system will look for an object in named `py` in `module`, which is unlikely to be what you actually want. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) for more details.